# Why can't 3GB of Data fit onto a 4.7GB Disc?

Tags: dvd

I would like to start by apologizing, this question will be vague as I'm not really sure what is going on, I'm using windows DVD maker to burn a DVD of a TV series that I want to watch on my DVD player downstairs, I'm trying to burn around 3GB of data to a 4.7GB disc, but for some reason, the program is saying that there is not enough space on the disc? It's also for some reason measuring the disc capacity in minutes instead of GB which is weird. Dees anyone have any ideas as to why this would happen?

Comment: What format is the videos in?  mp4,avi,mpg,mpeg, or etc

Comment: The file format is AVI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to burn a DVD to read on a DVD player, the data needs to be re-encoded to [a format your DVD player can read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video). That's in this format that the capacity in minutes of the DVD is calculated.

This format is probably much less compressed than the one of your original video, and thus the whole thing cannot fit on your DVD after being re-encoded.

Comment: Ah; a real shame.

Comment: @ShaunWild It is pretty easy to convert the video back into something that will both fit and play on a TV with Handbrake.

Comment: Can Handbrake burn to DVD's properly? I assume Window DVD maker won't work with Handbrake well.